# How to write a Npm Script Command that works cross platform

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift, bower-install

I'm trying to write a postinstall command that works with openshift to install bower dependancies.  I've managed to get it working which is great.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR bower install"
}
```

I'm trying to now improve that command so that I can run the following command locally on my windows PC.

```
npm install
```

It throws an error:

```
PS D:\dev\cgb14\code\trunk\solution\App> npm install

> warcher_app@1.0.0 postinstall D:\dev\cgb14\code\trunk\solution\App
> HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR node_modules/.bin/bower install

'HOME' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! warcher_app@1.0.0 postinstall: `HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR node_modules/.bin/bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the warcher_app@1.0.0 postinstall script 'HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR node_modules/.bin/bower install'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the warcher_app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR node_modules/.bin/bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls warcher_app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\dev\cgb14\code\trunk\solution\App\npm-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how I can improve the postinstall script to work on windows too?

I've been searching for documentation on what the npm command can take and see if there is a cross platform if exists statement.  I was thinking it should be something like if $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR exists, do this... else do something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, 5 minutes after I posted this I thought of something I hadn't tried yet.  A simple OR in the command worked.  I can now run this on both Windows and Openshift

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR bower install || bower install"
}
```